# How to normalize rewards in DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I want to use a Deep Q-Network for a specific problem. My immediate rewards ($r_t = 0$) are all zeros. But my terminal reward is a large positive value $(r_T=100$). How could I normalize rewards to stabilize the training?  I think clipping rewards to be in range $[0,1]$ makes training harder because it just forces most values to be near zero.

Comment: why do you need to scale the reward here? the problem I would be concerned with is that almost all of your rewards are non-zero. sparse reward environments can be difficult to solve. perhaps you should look at the Hindsight Experience Replay algorithm as a starting point for overcoming sparse rewards.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand what I should do. I need to Define a bigger state which contains smaller state and gradually decrease it's volume so at the end of training it is equal to smaller state.